# Replacing JQuery .val() with JS .value

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm going through some legacy code on a submission form and replacing JQuery w/ vanilla JS.

Right now, I have this function that uses .val() (JQuery) to grab the value for an undefined input:

```
myFunction: function(){
          var subscription = $('input[name="subscription_id"]').val();
          // Do something with subscription
}
```

When I run the code in my browser, I get no issues - the code is meant to work only if a subscription is passed into the input - if it's not there, we just get an undefined value.  The value returned by the JQuery combo of $() and .val() console logs to 'undefined'.

When I replace the JQuery with vanilla JS, like so:

```
myFunction: function(){
          var subscription = document.querySelector('input[name="subscription_id"]').value;
          // Do something with subscription
}
```

And then try to run my form, I get the following error in the console:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of null
```

Why is this happening?  And is there a workaround for this?  Any help is appreciated.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: check if the name  `subscription_id ` is available or not?

Comment: can you paste tour HTML?

Comment: The selector seems fine, but you might calling the function before input is attached/Dom loaded, etc. A snippet would be nice.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This happens because

```
document.querySelector('input[name="subscription_id"]')
```

does not exist. For vanilla js, you need to check if it exists first, then get the value if it does. jQuery has a silent fail for this.

```js
var element = document.querySelector('input[name="subscription_id"]');

// If it exists, return its value, or null
var subscription = element ? element.value : null;
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use a condition:

```
var elem = document.querySelector('input[name="subscription_id"]');
var subscription = elem ? elem.value : "";
```